# Setting UUID manually

Tags: fine-uploader

My server generates UUID for uploaded files, so i need to set UUID to the fileState after i received answer from upload server (to successfully use delete function). I added and implemented

```
setUuid: function(id, uuid)
```

In **UploadHandler**, **FineUploaderBasic** and **UploadHandlerXhr** to solve this issue but this involve editing fine-uploader sources, is there any other way around? I have feeling this can break something internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not passing the UUID back to fine uploader.  It would be simpler to associate your UUID with fine uploader's UUID server side.  You could maintain a map of associations in the session if you don't want to persist them.

Comment: This is possible solution, but this will require more engineering then just passing UUID back, and it will require server side modification to work with Fine Uploader properly.

Comment: @YoK Please file a feature request in the Fine Uploader github issue tracker.  I'd like to discuss your use case a bit more.  Perhaps we can accomodate this workflow in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue and found some [documentation](https://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html) that states you can set the UUID from the server side by returning it from the upload method. 
[click image where newUuid is being set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oMEZ.png)

Here is my return method using C#

```cs
return new FineUploaderResult(true, new { newUuid = attachmentId });
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.